# Mixed-Content Warning; Favicon blocked & culprit, but I don't have it specified

Tags: php, html, favicon, mixed-content

I have a simple web page with some jQuery ajax and PHP backside to easily view the `error_log` quickly and erase it for debugging and development purposes.

However, I noticed in FireFox that I have a mixed-content warning.  I checked on Chrome and it gave the error.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website/error_log.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://website/content.php?error=404'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This would be simpel to me as I would just have to find the Favicon and specify the correct path to it (since it's obviously not found and throwing it to the 404 page) using https.  However, I do not have a favicon specified on my page at all, so why is it giving me the mixed content notice?

**Error Log**

```
<?php
if(@$_GET["unlink"]=="yes") {
    if(file_exists('error_log')) {
        unlink('error_log');
    }
    exit(0);
}
if(@$_GET["ajax"]=="yes") {
    if(file_exists('error_log')) {
        //$file = file_get_contents('error_log');
        $fileLines = file('error_log');
        // Swap the order of the array
        $invertedLines = array_reverse($fileLines);
        echo '<pre>';
        //echo $file;
        for($i=0;$i<count($invertedLines);$i++) {
            echo $invertedLines[$i];
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo '<div align="center">The error log is currently empty.</div>';
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    exit(0);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Error Log</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
    $("#refresh").click(function(){
        refreshlog();
        clearInterval(interval);
        $('#refresh').val("Refreshed...");
        interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);  
    }); 
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        unlink();
    }); 

    
    var count = 30; 
    function counter() {
        if(count===30) {
            refreshlog();
        }
        count--;
        //console.log(count);
        $('#refresh').val('Refresh Error Log ('+count+')');
        if (count === 0) {
            count = 30;
        }
    }
    function refreshlog() {
        $.ajax({url: "./error_log.php?ajax=yes", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    }
    function unlink() {
        $.ajax({url: "./error_log.php?unlink=yes", success: function(result){
            refreshlog();
        }});
    }
    
});
</script>
<style>
pre
{
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 650px!ie7;
  padding-bottom: 20px!ie7;
  max-height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><input type="button" id='refresh' style="border: 1px solid #050; color: #050; padding: 5px; margin: 3px; cursor: pointer;" value="Refresh Error Log"><input type="button"id='delete' style="border: 1px solid #C00; color: #c00; padding: 5px; margin: 3px; cursor: pointer;" value="Clear Error Log"></div>
<hr>
<div id='div1'></div>
<hr>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Some browsers automatically request `/favicon.ico`, if no other favicon URL was explicitly specified. Here in your instance, that request appears to have been _redirected to_ `http://website/content.php?error=404` - which indicates your setup of the 404 error document is wrong. (It should not be using HTTP, but even more importantly, it should not redirect externally in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe I was not aware of this!  Is there any way to tell where the browser is looking for the favicon?  Also, I assume the 404 setup is that it shouldn't be directing to a specific URL and instead be local `ErrorDocument /content.php?error=404`, correct?

Comment: Where, `/favicon.ico` directly under the domain root. And yes, a relative URL should be used for ErrorDocument.